# How to write html code inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

`<script type="text/javascript">` 
html code here 
`</script>`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Really not enough information here for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: I just want to write html code inside javascript

Comment: if you are comparing php to your question, clearly it is not posible. you cannot write inline html code inside a `<script>` tag. you cannot compare php with javascript, since php is a server side code while javascript is a client side code.

Comment: how about saying, "You can't". The OP's question is not clear so that would be enough answer.

Comment: Clear (if badly worded) question which can be answered.  Voting to reopen

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you want `document.write`?

Comment: Look i want to write html code inside javascript. You know what html is ??

Comment: @zoro: Do _you_ know what HTML is?

Comment: @zoro: Try to be nice, you want something from us! And actually this is a correct answer. There are other ways to create HTML elements via JavaScript but I assume this is not what you want.